# Why is my while loop not working in paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

When I run this code, I see nothing but a blank(white) Panel and I would like to know why.

Here is my code:

**Graph.java**

```
public class Graph extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -397959590385297067L;
    int screen=-1;
    int x=10;
    int y=10;
    int dx=1;
    int dy=1;       
    boolean shouldrun=true;
    imageStream imget=new imageStream();

        protected void Loader(Graphics g){

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0,0,x,y);
            x=x+1;
            y=y+2;

        }


        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
                while(shouldrun){
                    Loader(g);   
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }    
                }   
        }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Do not ever call `Thread.sleep()` on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)!!!

This causes the thread that actually redraws the screen and makes controls responsive to stop doing *anything*.

[For animations, use a `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). Don't worry about writing the while loop yourself, just tell the `Timer` to fire every so often, and change the values of `x` and `y` inside that timer. Something like:

```
// this is an **inner** class of Graph
public class TimerActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
}

// snip
```

```
private final Timer yourTimer;

public Graph() {
    yourTimer = new Timer(2000, new TimerActionListener());
    timer.start();
}
```

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0,0,x,y);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, what he says! 1+

Comment: its not an animation tho,the idea is to have levels in the game,a loadscreen and a menu.And i wanted a loop to rerun the graphics depending on an integer screen.

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer The Event Dispatch Thread automatically does the work of your loop for you. **You don't need to worry about making it repeatedly redrawn, as Swing does it for you like magic!** This code is quite similar to the code you provided; you were calling `x=x+1` in your `Loader` method, this does the same thing, except with a `Timer` instead of a while loop.

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer If your intention is not to animate, you don't really need a loop nor a timer. You can simply trigger a next level screen with conditions or some listeners.

Answer (score 4):

You never change the state of shouldrun within the loop -- so it will never end.

Also, never call `Thread.sleep(...)` within a painting method. This method is for painting and can never be put to sleep, else the GUI will be put to sleep, will be frozen.

Comment: Oh,i see.And yeah ik it would never end.But how should i make it iterate?with a repaint in the main code?...ignore this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your paintComponent method should only handle all painting and nothing else (if possible). You should not implement your program loop within paintComponent.

The blank screen can be caused by a number of reasons. You can easily debug it manually by commenting off certain section of your codes and run it. See whether it is still blank.

At least from what I see here, your paintComponent will give your problems.

If you want an animation, you can:

1. Use a swing timer
2. Create a loop in a new thread (not Event Dispatch Thread). Your loop will look something like this:

As below:

```
while(running){
    update();
    render();
    try(
        Thread.sleep(1000/fps);
    )catch(InterruptedException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note: To make a proper loop for animation, you will need more than that.

Comment: "if possible" it should really only be painting, else there is something major flawed with the code.

Comment: @durron597 Take a look at this sample given by the university? http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html

Comment: @durron597 The simplest approach would be using timer, but if the program/game gets complicated, it will be better to create a Thread and run the game loop within that thread instead of doing everything in the EDT isn't it? So from that perspective, it is not so absolute that Java animation must be done with only swing timers.

Comment: @user3437460 I agree that sophisticated game developers should not be using `Timer` and should instead write their own variable framerate game loops, but that's why beyond the scope of this question and OP's current skill level.

Comment: @durron597 Instead of telling him straight which is better, I choose to tell him (and future users) the possible options. They will choose what is better for them. I just don't want to give him a wrong impression that swing timer is the only possible option. :)